# Warrior vs Antimatter

Tags: cosmic-encounter

The effects on the Anti-Matter race card seem somewhat unclear; the net effect seems to be that each side in an encounter wants to play a low attack card in order to win. This means that more ships still increases your chance to win (since they subtract rather than add to the attack card). However, the Warrior card says to 'add' to their final total depending on how many accrued tokens they have.

Does this mean that the Warrior race becomes more and more ineffective against the Anti-Matter over time, until it effectively cannot win?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. (As Anti-Matter's opponent, anyway. As an ally, Warrior is just fine.)

Anti-Matter's power isn't so much unclear as kind of complicated:
 - Anti-Matter's tokens subtract.
 - Ally tokens subtract.
 - Opposing main player's tokens add.
 - Low total wins.

And if you think Warrior's bad against Anti-Matter, spare some sympathy for the poor Virus. (No? Not really surprising.)